# Error while deploying Rails App to Heroku with Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, webpack

Im having some issues while trying to deploy a new Rails app to heroku that contains webpack, the server locally runs perfectly.

Here is the error:

```
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        /tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:283
remote:              compilation.hooks.processAssets.tapPromise({
remote:                                              ^
remote:        
remote:        TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapPromise' of undefined
remote:            at /tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/compression-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:283:39
remote:            at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
remote:            at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
remote:            at Compiler.newCompilation (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:630:30)
remote:            at /tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:667:29
remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
remote:            at Compiler.compile (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:662:28)
remote:            at /tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:321:11
remote:            at Compiler.readRecords (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:529:11)
remote:            at /tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:318:10
remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
remote:            at /tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:315:19
remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
remote:            at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
remote:            at Compiler.run (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:312:24)
remote:            at processOptions (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:353:14)
remote:            at /tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:364:3
remote:            at Object.parse (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:576:18)
remote:            at /tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
remote:            at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:366:3)
remote:            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
remote:            at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
remote:            at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
remote:            at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
remote:            at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
remote:            at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
remote:            at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_285fb393/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
remote:            at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
remote:
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rails_api_base",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@activeadmin/activeadmin": "^2.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.3-5",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.3-5",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.3-5",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.1.1",
    "arctic_admin": "3.2.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "compression-webpack-plugin": ">=4.0.0",
    "dot-prop": ">=5.2.0",
    "is-svg": ">=4.2.2",
    "node-forge": ">=0.10.0",
    "ssri": ">=8.0.1",
    "y18n": ">=4.0.1"
  }
}
```

As far as I read, it seems to be some incompatibility but Im not being able to solve it.

Comment: The package.json won't tell us the relevant versions you're using - what version of webpack / compression-webpack-plugin? See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin/issues/223

Comment: Essentially you may want to try upgrading webpack/compression-webpack-plugin

Comment: To reproduce locally you can try blowing away your local npm packages and reinstalling. npm may not be pulling down the same version on heroku as you got when you last ran an install locally